# Any issues with mixing libraries with and without std=c++0x

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I am writing a library that must depend libraries that are not presently compiling with support for the new standard.  I would like to compile a library which must depend on those libraries with std=c++0x.  Are there any problems with doing this?

Comment: headers may be an issue, see here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt01ch03s02.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you mix libraries compiled with different compiler options then you must ensure that the ABI for the data types in the interface is the same. Some data types (such as `std::string`) have different interfaces and requirements between C++03 and C++0x, so interfaces that use them must be careful.

If your interfaces only use built-in types and your own classes, and these do not themselves use any standard library classes then all should be OK. Otherwise you will need to check the specific subset you are using.

Comment: Only using C at the interface isn't sufficient in general.  It doesn't work when linking statically, under Unix, it requires special options to `dlopen` when linking dynamically, and under Windows, there was a bug in the library pulled in by /MD or /MDd which meant that it would fail if either of the libraries used `std::string` and were compiled with different options.  (I've heard that this bug has been fixed in VC10.)

Comment: @James: I agree in general, but this issue is tagged **gcc**. As I understand it, the intent of the gcc library developers is that provided you should be able to use `-std=c++98` and `-std=c++0x` code in the same program, as long as the interface between these bits of code only uses compatible types. e.g. on Linux there is only one `libstdc++.so` binary, used by both `-std=c++98` and `-std=c++0x` code alike.

Comment: There's the intent of the developers, and there's what actually happens.  I've had problems getting `dynamic_cast` to work when it was executed in one `.so`, and the object was constructed in another.  And with the options to `dlopen` necessary for the `dynamic_cast` to work, you will end up sharing some of the other functions, including member functions of `std::vector`, etc.  And the size and layout of `std::vector` depends on compiler options; you don't even have to change versions for it to fail.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is no, unless the vendor explicitly guarantees it (and even then).  Practically speaking, all code linked together must use the same standard library, and be compiled with the same version of the compiler, using the same options.  There are ways around this, at least for dynamically linked libraries, but they only work if the interface between the libraries is pure C, and you take special steps when linking (special options with `dlopen`---neither library uses `std::string` in VC++ pre-version 10, etc.).  Otherwise, you're looking for trouble.